# Rspec Integration Test not Cleaning the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

The database is not being cleaned after each integration test. The value stays in the database.

Is there an option I should have to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner is what you need.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using `before(:all)` hooks, be aware that these hooks are executed *before* the transaction associated to the fixture is opened. This means that **any data created by before(:all) hooks will not be rolled back by transactional fixtures**. You can read more [in the RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions).

I just wanted to mention this because I was bit by it and my initial instinct was to jump to Database Cleaner (which wound up not being needed and eventually not working).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! This is a non-obvious RSpec gotcha for sure.

Answer (score 3):

[How do I prepare test database(s) for Rails rspec tests without running rake spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916126/how-do-i-prepare-test-databases-for-rails-rspec-tests-without-running-rake-spe/18039499#18039499)

My answer there might be of interest to you. it's a nice solution. For your case, you would probably need something like

```
config.after :each do
  ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each(&:delete_all)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here for a tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

It describes Database Cleaner besides Rspec and Capybara

Comment: Isn't there a way without Database Cleaner?

Comment: There is, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916126/how-do-i-prepare-test-databases-for-rails-rspec-tests-without-running-rake-spe/18039499#18039499

Answer (score 2):

You want DatabaseCleaner, but you may find that the `:truncation` strategy is a bit too slow to run all the time. It's really only necessary for integration tests, so you can do this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'database_cleaner'
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:each) do |group|
  # The strategy needs to be set before we call DatabaseCleaner.start
  case group.example.metadata[:type]
  when :feature
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

# spec/features/your_feature_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "An integration test", :type => :feature do
end

# spec/model/your_model_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "A unit test" do
end
```

Obviously, this only applies if you're doing integration tests with RSpec directly vs. doing them with Cucumber.

Comment: In rspec 3.4, We can check that via `group.metadata[:type]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Configure transactional examples for each individual test.
2. Configure transactional examples for all the tests.

If you opt for option 1: At the top of the spec file, after:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Add:

```
RSpec.configure {|c| c.use_transactional_examples = true }
```

That will roll back the transactions after each example.

2.If you want to configure it globally, then, in the spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
config.use_transactional_examples = true # Add this
...
end
```