# rake db:test:prepare does not setup test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, testing, rake-task

I am using Rails 4.0.0.rc1 with sqlite3 and trying to setup the test database for testing. `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` did not create the tables in the test database. After following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916126/how-do-i-prepare-test-databases-for-rails-rspec-tests-without-running-rake-spe) I managed to setup the test database by running `bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test -t` What can be the reason for task `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` to not to setup the database.

Below is the output of the 2 rake tasks.

```
indika@indika-F3E:~/Documents/my_app$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare -t
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Execute db:test:prepare
indika@indika-F3E:~/Documents/my_app$ 

indika@indika-F3E:~/Documents/my_app$ bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test -t
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:load
-- create_table("questions", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.2590s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0025s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20130518181153, ["/home/indika/Documents/my_app/db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0007s
indika@indika-F3E:~/Documents/my_app$
```

The database configuration in `database.yaml` is like this.

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Please note that my problem was solved. But I am curious to know what had gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` works with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0.rc1
rake db:test:prepare for some reason doesn't work with the new versions.

Comment: Thanks... Does anyone knows why?

Comment: It was removed in rails 4 and is now maintained automatically.  See: [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13528)