# Simulate read-only database with Rspec / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm currently running the unit tests of my RoR application with Rspec.
One of my controllers should return a HTTP status 500 when it can not write a new entity to the database.
I wish to test this behaviour and would like temporarily to mark my database is read-only.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

I tried the technique mentioned in "[How do I prepare test database(s) for Rails rspec tests without running rake spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916126/how-do-i-prepare-test-databases-for-rails-rspec-tests-without-running-rake-spe)", but this approach does not work for me (since the controller reads from the database before writing to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just mock out corresponding Model requests, if you are testing the controller.
So, what exception should `Model.create` throw? Try something like this:

```
Model.stub(:create).and_raise(ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord)
```

Comment: I guess this should work when I'd be using the `Model.create` method, but I'm using `Model.new` in combination with `instance.save`. Not quite sure how I would use `stub` in this case.

Comment: Maybe, stub `save` then?

Comment: I think, if you want to *unit* test, then go with stubbing. If you would go with feature tests - than manipulate the DB.

Comment: I tried stubbing `save` but that does not seem to work. I had another look at my code and it turns out I can use create directly, instead of using the two methods mentioned before. I've implemented this and used your example. Seems to work just fine. Thanks! :)